# Handle EVT_MOTION in wxMDIParentFrame

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Main parent frame class `myMainFrame` which is derived from `wxMDIParentFrame` class seems to be not handling mouse events. Issue can be easily reproduced with a sample MDI application.

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(myMainFrame,wxMDIParentFrame)
EVT_MOTION(myMainFrame::OnMouseMove)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void myMainFrame::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
//...
}
```

I called

```
Connect(0, wxEVT_MOTION, (wxObjectEventFunction) (wxEventFunction) (wxMouseEventFunction) OnMouseMove);
```

from `myMainFrame` constructor, but that didn't fix the issue.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have trouble receiving mouse events from the parent MDI frame because it's entirely covered by other windows. In wxGTK, it's basically a `wxNotebook`, with child frames being its pages. In wxMSW, it's a real frame, but it contains what Windows calls "client window", that in turn contains MDI children, so it's this window, not exposed by wxWidgets, that gets all the events.

In short, this is not supported and very unlikely to ever be.

Comment: Thanks. Any workarounds? My MDI application has an auto-hide toolbar on the main window. That toolbar displays bitmaps - "Button1", "Button2", "Min", "Max", "Close". Entire functionality is driven from the toolbar. All I want is an Auto-hide Toolbar, my MDI app does show the toolbar but it is just that Auto-hide isn't working. Can I achieve auto hide functionality or something similar using any alternatives?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to associate toolbar with the child frames?

Comment: No, I wanted single toolbar on main frame.

Comment: The only (imperfect) other solution I see is to use a timer event handler which checks whether the mouse is over the toolbar and hides it if it isn't during a few consecutive checks.